# Google sheets rename column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a problem changing the name of some columns in sheets. I have tried a few things but keep getting error messages. Latest is :

> ReferenceError: "columns" is not defined

Not sure how I define "columns"

Here is a copy of my script for doing various other things with a sheet.

```
function delete_columns()
{
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
    // Columns start at "1" - this will delete the first two columns in            sheet.deleteRows(1,2)
    sheet.deleteColumns(199,9);
    sheet.deleteColumns(77,121);
    sheet.deleteColumns(47,29);
    sheet.deleteColumns(43,1);
    sheet.deleteColumns(39,1);
    sheet.deleteColumns(30,7);
    sheet.deleteColumns(9,22);
    sheet.deleteColumns(6,3);
    sheet.deleteColumns(4,1);
     // This will resize the columns to match content
    sheet.autoResizeColumn(4);
    sheet.autoResizeColumn(5);
    sheet.autoResizeColumn(6);
    sheet.autoResizeColumn(7); 
    sheet.autoResizeColumn(8);
    sheet.autoResizeColumn(9);
    sheet.autoResizeColumn(12);
     // This will rename columns
    columns[5].setName("PO");
    columns[6].setName("Company");
    columns[7].setName("Address");
    columns[8].setName("Address - 2");
    columns[9].setName("City");
    columns[10].setName("State");
    columns[11].setName("Zip");

}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Columns don't have names, or said differently, their names ( A,B,C,D etc) can't be changed.

You can use headers in the first row to play that role, you can also [freeze](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#setFrozenRows(Integer)) that row so that the "names" remain visible all the time.

Setting values in the first row is pretty straightforward, use a 2 dimension array and a `setValues()`.  From you code it would be :

```
var headers = [['','','','','PO','Company','Address','Address - 2','City','State','Zip']];
```

Then simply  :

```
sheet.getRange(1,1,1,headers[0].length).setValues(headers);
sheet.setFrozenRows(1);
```

Comment: Sorry if I didn't make my problem more clear.  I am not trying to change the Column names, A, B, C, D etc.  Row 1 is for my headers.  I copy a spreadsheet from a site.  It's 100 + columns.  My script shortens it to 12 columns.  Trying to change via the script the names in the 1st row.  Example: column E, header is "Reference #1", I want to change this to PO, 6 columns of Ship to ....., want to change those to Company, Address, City, State, Zip.  Tried to use - columns[5].setName("PO"); but get the error "ReferenceError: "columns" is not defined"

Comment: Ok, so my example should do the job